# Dynamics AX Security Keys Disappearing

Tags: security, version-control, dynamics-ax-2009

AX 2009: I created Security keys and assigned them to all my objects.  Everything worked perfectly, until we went to install at the client site and found our keys were no longer assigned to objects in the xpo.  Going back to our development server, the keys were no longer assigned there either.  We assumed one of the developers deleted or renamed keys, causing them to drop from our objects.

However, a week later-after adding all the keys back in--most of the keys have dropped from our objects on the development server again.

Source control is turned on.  Checking the version history, the last check-in comment for most items is "Added security key back to object."  Whatever is causing the keys to drop is happening outside source control.

Any ideas or suggestions as to what could be happening?

How do we prevent it in the future?

Thanks

PS. Not certain if it's relevant, but our custom label files periodically get wiped out as well, even though they are also in source control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brad,

How did you deploy your solution? The best practice is to ship the entire layer(s) as AOD files. If you import the XPO files it's possible to import the table node before the security keys.

I am not sure what causes the label file issue, but what I discovered is that I can use the Label::flush() function to periodically flush the labels to the ald files. In addition to that it's good idea to backup the ald and aod files on a regular basis.

HTH,
VM

Comment: We typically deploy through XPOs.  I hadn't thought of deploying AOD files, but will look into that.

Comment: The security keys are actually disappearing from our development server.  We can literally check out an object, assign keys, check it back in, and come back the next day, and the keys will be detached from our objects again with no check-ins or outs happening in source control.

Comment: If you check-in both the security keys and the tables does this make any difference? In your dev instance do you import xpo files from different servers or from different layers with the 'keep IDs' option checked?

Comment: I've tried checking the project all in at once, and in pieces.  For importing, we typically bring in the entire project without IDs.  I also started importing keys first, followed by the rest of the project.  Seems to be working so far.  We'll see how long it holds.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I have had objects disappear from XPO's in the past. Usually a restart of the AOS (and then a re-export of the XPO) solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently experienced a situation where we released code via an XPO and two objects (trying to determine if more objects have been affected) were found to be removed from the destination AOT (they were not part of the XPO).